# How to export an editable chart to excel which is created with Mschart?

Tags: asp.net, mschart, microsoft-chart-controls

I want to export the chart which is created with mschart to excel.

I want  real chart in excel which user can change it's values not an image of chart.

What's the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that.
MS chart exports a binary image (jpg, png, bmp, etc.).

You can only export the underlying data and use Excel to create it's own chart.